# Google Fusion map not visible in IE9

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-9

I have just made my first Google Fusion map with the encrypted ID instead of the numeric ID. It look like it should – but only in Chrome and FireFox.

http://www.kaasogmulvad.dk/unv/a4/aa2009.htm

When I try to open it in IE9, the map area is grey. Only the legend looks fine.

I used the code of this map as a template to get started:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/fusiontableslayer_example_4b8296dfe1f18ec9a830c4329e2cfafe.frame
This map works fine in IE9. So I wonder what's the problem with mine?

Answer (score 0):

your page works fine for me.
maybe is something with your browser.

[image: ie9]

Comment: The Map type is grey for me in IE8, the Satellite type works though.  The HTML is not valid, but that doesn't seem to change anything and there is nothing obvious in the CSS.

Comment: Very strange. I have tried on two different computers in two different locations, none will show it in IE9.

Comment: This might not be the best solution, but I removed <!DOCTYPE html> at the top and an extra </div> at the end. At now it works in IE9.